# How to get RGB value of a pixel from a CGImageRef object?

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, pixel

I'm trying to get an RGB value of a pixel from a CGImageRef object. I know that I need to create a context or something but, how do I do this?

Comment: see my answer on [How to detect a RGB on a point][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270923/how-to-read-rgb-pixel-data-on-iphone/22379366#22379366

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This post](http://www.markj.net/iphone-uiimage-pixel-color/) shows you how to do it.

Comment: I think [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042830/retrieving-a-pixel-alpha-value-for-a-uiimage) was better -- it does it with a one pixel image instead of rendering the whole image to grab one pixel.