# Help with image processing in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, matlab

I'm working with an image processing tool in MATLAB. How can I convert MATLAB code to Objective-C?

Here are some of the tasks I want to do:

- I want to rotate an oblique line to normal.
- I have algorıthm that converts an colored image to black & white. (How can I access pixel color values in Objective-C?)
- In the function `getrgbfromimage`, how can I access output of pixel values to consol?
- How can I run a function (`getrotatedımage`) on each element of an array?

Answer (score 0):

Quartz 2D (aka. Core Graphics) is the 2D drawing API in iOS. Quartz will, most likely, do everything you're looking for. I recommend checking out the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html) in the documentation. For your specific requests check out these sections:

- *Colors and Color Spaces* - for color and b&w images
- *Transforms* - for rotating or performing any affine transform
- *Bitmap Images and Image Masks* - for information on the underlying image data

As for running a function on each element of an array, you can use the block iteration API (as long as your app can require iOS 4.0 or higher). An example:

```
[myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id item, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
  doSomethingWith(item);
}];
```

If you just want to call a method on each item in the array, there is also:

```
[myArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(doSomething)];
```

Answer (score 0):

CGBitmapContext will get pixel values from an image.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html

This has same demo code.

[Retrieving a pixel alpha value for a UIImage (MonoTouch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597198/retrieving-a-pixel-alpha-value-for-a-uiimage-monotouch)

printf will dump the RGB values to the console.

NSArray or NSMutableArray will hold your images and a simple for loop will let you iterate through them.