# uiimageview or uibutton not square

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uibutton

Is there anyway to make an uiimageview or uibutton that is not squared?

I'd need several images that can be clickable but dont have a squared shape.

Is there anyway to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this thread,

[Simple way of using irregular shaped buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755572/simple-way-of-using-irregular-shaped-buttons)

Hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom button to get a different shape on the button.
A usefull link (though for xcode 3) is here: http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/2009/09/how-to-create-custom-buttons-in-interface-builder/

For UIImageView it shouldn't matter much.. Any part of the UIImageView that doesn't get filled by the picture, stays transparant if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a button and set its `image` or `background image` as required

good luck