# Create an UIButton with a particular shape: how?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simple way of using irregular shaped buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755572/simple-way-of-using-irregular-shaped-buttons)

I found examples about creating a rect or round UIButton.

Is possible to create an UIButton with a particular shape (e.g. a heart, a star and so on)?

How?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish that is using:

```
UIButton *myButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myButton setFrame:CRectMake( 0, 0, imWidth, imHeight)];
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shabadabada.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And that would get you a simple button ... though it is not actually shaped like a "shabadabada" (:P) it will be a squared button.

To do a truly custom shaped "button" you would have to implement from the UIView class:

```
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect;
```

And you would have to draw your shape point by point, here's a simple guide on doing [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_Graphics_Drawing_Tutorial_using_Quartz_2D).

And also respond to the following methods:

```
– touchesBegan:withEvent:
– touchesMoved:withEvent:
– touchesEnded:withEvent:
– touchesCancelled:withEvent:
```

Or just to:

```
– addGestureRecognizer:
```