# How get pixel data from nativescript Image or ImageAsset

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I am trying to get image data from imageAsset in native script, but I can't get pixel data from my image. How can I do that?

```
onCameraButtonTap(imageComponentRef: any, htmlDocRef: any): void {
    camera.takePicture().then((imageAsset) => {
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = imageAsset;
        imageComponentRef.src = imageAsset;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

I mean something like this: `image.getRGB(23,45)`, getting pixel rgb data from a coordinate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **Android** in NativeScript:

You need to use the android native bitmap and [Color](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color) class to get the RGB.

Declare `android` on Top of your class e.g.

```
declare let android: any;

@Component({
....
{)
```

and add the folloing code in your takePicture function

```
camera.takePicture().then((imageAsset) => {
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = imageAsset;
        imageComponentRef.src = imageAsset;
        const imagePath = imageAsset.android;
        const imageAndroidDrawable = android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath);
            const imageAndroidBitmap = android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
            const pixel = imageAndroidBitmap.getPixel(23, 45);
            const redValue =  android.graphics.Color.red(pixel);
            const blueValue = android.graphics.Color.blue(pixel);
            const greenValue = android.graphics.Color.green(pixel);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no plugin yet, but it seems to be a few lines of code with [iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773245/simple-way-to-read-pixel-color-values-from-an-png-image-on-the-iphone) / [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807360/how-to-get-pixel-color-in-android) native apis.

Refer the docs to converting [Objective C](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/Marshalling-Overview) / [Java](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/marshalling/java-to-js) into JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nativescript-bitmap-factory to get a pixel from bitmap object

```
var BitmapFactory = require("nativescript-bitmap-factory");

var colorSelected;

var bmp = BitmapFactory.asBitmap(imageAsset);

bmp.dispose(() => function {

     colorSelected = bmp.getPoint(23,45);

})
```