# Simple Tappable Non-Rectangular Shape

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, user-interface

I have to create a very simple GUI for an iPad application.

I have a 1024x768 png and I want to use this file for the GUI. I have to make an area of this png tappable and able to run some action. This area is not a rectangle (it's a trapezoid) so I can't create a button. Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it in code by overriding `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` and `- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` in the view that's displaying the image. that'll mean you have to decide whether a point is within the touch area of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Make a UIImageView that displays an image which shows the trapezoid and is otherwise transparent.

Turn on the UIImageView's `userInteractionEnabled` to make it tappable.

Put a UITapGestureRecognizer on the UIImageView to respond to the tap.

In the tap gesture recognizer's action handler, respond only if the point where the user tapped is non-transparent. To learn whether the point the user touched is transparent, see [Retrieving a pixel alpha value for a UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042830/retrieving-a-pixel-alpha-value-for-a-uiimage/3763313#3763313).