# Pixel analysis on Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, uiimage, pixel

I maybe asking for the impossible, but I need an economic way to check which pixels of an image fall roughly into these [categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ci0n.jpg).
I want to do this on the iPhone, and that's the problem (processing capacity).
There is this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics), but the process seems too long. Maybe something like .NET's GetPixel() might work.

Help? :)

Comment: When you say "too long", you mean that you've tried it and profiled it, and the _running time_ is too long?

Comment: @Josh I ran the process with an NSLog instead of the pixel analysis and it took like 1.5 minutes. If I put all the code from the post above it will take forever, right?

Comment: @Fiire NSLog is SOOO slow, it will take MUCH longer than manipulating pixels.  My pixel manipulation method (compression) takes about 0.5 seconds, but with NSLog included it takes 5 or 6 minutes.

Comment: Also see this creative solution -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/3763313/1155387

Comment: What have you tried? What format are your images in? Are they UIImages? How large are they?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you are calling "falling into categories", but you might try using [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) and create a custom filter.  GPUImage uses OpenGL and hardware acceleration and can be considerably faster than pulling apart the pixel data in a single thread.