# Detect touches only on non-transparent pixels of UIImageView, efficiently

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, uiimageview, hittest

How would you detect touches only on non-transparent pixels of a `UIImageView`, efficiently?

Consider an image like the one below, displayed with `UIImageView`. The goal is be to make the gesture recognisers respond only when the touch happens in the non-transparent (black in this case) area of the image.

[image]

### Ideas

- Override [`hitTest:withEvent:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/hitTest:withEvent:) or [`pointInside:withEvent:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/pointInside:withEvent:), although this approach might be terribly inefficient as these methods get called many times during a touch event.
- Checking if a single pixel is transparent might create unexpected results, as fingers are bigger than one pixel. Checking a circular area of pixels around the hit point, or trying to find a transparent path towards an edge might work better.

### Bonus

- It'd be nice to differentiate between outer and inner transparent pixels of an image. In the example, the transparent pixels inside the zero should also be considered valid.
- What happens if the image has a transform?
- Can the image processing be hardware accelerated?

Comment: I open-sourced what we ended up doing here: https://github.com/robotmedia/RMShapedImageView

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's my quick implementation: (based on [Retrieving a pixel alpha value for a UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042830/retrieving-a-pixel-alpha-value-for-a-uiimage))

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //Using code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042830/retrieving-a-pixel-alpha-value-for-a-uiimage

    unsigned char pixel[1] = {0};
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixel,
                                                 1, 1, 8, 1, NULL,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaOnly);
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(-point.x, -point.y)];
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGFloat alpha = pixel[0]/255.0f;
    BOOL transparent = alpha < 0.01f;

    return !transparent;
}
```

This assumes that the image is in the same coordinate space as the `point`.  If scaling goes on, you may have to convert the `point` before checking the pixel data.

Appears to work pretty quickly to me.  I was measuring approx. 0.1-0.4 ms for this method call.  It doesn't do the interior space, and is probably not optimal.

Comment: Any idea on now to make this work when the image has been scaled? I can't seem to make it work,  Works fine though if the image is full size (not scaled)

Comment: I would use the ratio of x and y distances, then do the same test on the original image, but based on converting the ratio. Eg: 30% of 200 pixels is 60 pixels. If the original image is 100 pixels, then test on 30 pixels.

Answer (score 6):

On github, you can find a [project by Ole Begemann](http://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton) which extends `UIButton` so that it only detects touches where the button's image is not transparent.

Since `UIButton` is a subclass of `UIView`, adapting it to `UIImageView` should be straightforward.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Sergio. The thing with that project is that it only checks a single pixel, and the way it does it is not very efficient when extended to many pixels. Still, it's a great starting point. :)

Comment: Thanks Sergio. You saved my day with that link! Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you need to do it really fast, you need to precalculate the mask.

Here's how to extract it:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"some_image.png"];
NSData *data = (NSData *) CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage));
unsigned char *pixels = (unsigned char *)[data bytes];
BOOL *mask = (BOOL *)malloc(data.length);
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
  mask[i >> 2] = pixels[i + 3] == 0xFF; // alpha, I hope
}
// TODO: save mask somewhere
```

Or you could use the 1x1 bitmap context solution to precalculate the mask.
Having a mask means you can check any point with the cost of one indexed memory access.

As for checking a bigger area than one pixel - I would check pixels on a circle with the center in the touch point. About 16 points on the circle should be enough.

Detecting also inner pixels: another precalculation step - you need to find the convex hull of the mask.
You can do that using the "Graham scan" algorithm http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0109/algorithm_0109.htm
Then either fill that area in the mask, or save the polygon and use a point-in-polygon test instead.

And finally, if the image has a transform, you need to convert the point coordinates from screen space to image space, and then you can just check the precalculated mask.