# How to detect tapgesture on UIImage?

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage, uitapgesturerecognizer

My application require touch events only on UIImage not on UIImageVIew , How to discard the taps of UIImageView and only accept if tap gesture is recognized on UIImage part .

Thanks, In advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect touches only on non-transparent pixels of UIImageView, efficiently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291919/detect-touches-only-on-non-transparent-pixels-of-uiimageview-efficiently)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a tapgesture to UIImage. it can only be added to the UIImageview.