# Detect touch on irregular shaped images that are closely placed inside a UIView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, collision-detection

I have situation where large number of images are placed closed to one another inside a view, each image has its own image-view. The images are high resolution pngs and are irregular shape such as shape of a country. The problem is that I wish to do something uniquely when an image is touched. However, the frames of image-views are all rectangles and overlap neighboring images and hence correct detection is not possible.

I would really appreciate any guidance in this regard. Please let me know if I have not clearly explained my problem.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Check this question ([Detect touches only on non-transparent pixels of UIImageView, efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291919/detect-touches-only-on-non-transparent-pixels-of-uiimageview-efficiently))

On github, you can find a [project by Ole Begemann](http://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton) which extends `UIButton` so that it only detects touches where the button's image is not transparent.

Since `UIButton` is a subclass of `UIView`, adapting it to `UIImageView` should be straightforward.

Hope this helps.