# Trying to have objects only intersect with image and not the transparency in the rectangle of the image

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5.0.1

I tried looking around for this quite a bit but i don't really know how to word it. Right now I have my code to detect wether two UIimages intersect but it checks if the square around the image intersects. The image is a triangle shape so that doesn't work well. Where should I look to have it only detect that the images have intersected if the actual images intersect and not the transparency in the square around each image. Thank you!

Comment: Are you making a game??

Comment: yes i am making a game

Comment: I think may want try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291919/detect-touches-only-on-non-transparent-pixels-of-uiimageview-efficiently?answertab=votes#tab-top)