# Detect touch within Sprite texture and not the entire frame iOS Swift SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am working with SpriteKit right now and I came across a problem that seems simple but I couldn't find anything on the internet. I have three buttons that are shaped like parallelograms stacked on top of each other and it looks like this:
[Screenshot of buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QoWC.jpg)

```
let button = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playbutton")
let leaderButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "leaderbutton")
let homeButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "homebutton")

    button.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
    addChild(button)

    leaderButton.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2 - button.size.height/2)
    addChild(leaderButton)

    homeButton.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2 - button.size.height)
    addChild(homeButton)

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if button.containsPoint(location) {
            button.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(0.8, duration: 0.1))
        }
        else if leaderButton.containsPoint(location) {
            leaderButton.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(0.8, duration: 0.1))
        }
        else if homeButton.containsPoint(location) {
            homeButton.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(0.8, duration: 0.1))
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I am detecting touches. The problem is that they overlap because the sprite is actually a rectangle so when i try and tap on the top left of the second button, the top button detects it. I was wondering of there is a way to detect touch only in the texture like how you can set the physics body to a texture.
Thanks for any help you can give me!

Link works now.

So I tried this:

```
    button.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
    button.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "playbutton"), size: button.size)
    button.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    addChild(button)

    leaderButton.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2 - button.size.height/2)
    leaderButton.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "leaderbutton"), size: leaderButton.size)
    leaderButton.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    addChild(leaderButton)

    homeButton.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2 - button.size.height)
    homeButton.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "homebutton"), size: homeButton.size)
    homeButton.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    addChild(homeButton)

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if physicsWorld.bodyAtPoint(location)?.node == button {
            button.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(0.8, duration: 0.1))
            print("play")
        }
        if physicsWorld.bodyAtPoint(location)?.node == leaderButton {
            leaderButton.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(0.8, duration: 0.1))
            print("leader")
        }
        if physicsWorld.bodyAtPoint(location)?.node == homeButton {
            homeButton.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(0.8, duration: 0.1))
        }
    }
}
```

It still registers the full frame and not just the physics body. See the link to see the buttons and how their coordinates intersect.

Comment: `leaderButton` is above `button`? I can't imagine why they will overlap because they should be just next to each other using your code.

Comment: Add `skView.showsPhysics = true` in GameViewController.swift to check button's physics body. Is it parallelograms or rectangle?

Comment: Could you try using `SKRegion`? You can construct 3 regions of a shape that matches your button outline, and in the touch event, check if the touch location is in any of the regions...

Comment: When I show physics, it shows the physics body wrapping around the texture perfectly. For some reason the code for detecting if the touch was in the physics body doesn't work. The middle button doesn't even work which I can't explain either even though it has the same code as the other two buttons

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you attach a physics body to each button, you can detect which physics body your touch lands on.

You can generate a physics body from the button's texture (assuming the button is an `SKSpriteNode`) using `SKPhysicsBody(texture:size:)` or `SKPhysicsBody(texture:alphaThreshold:size:)`, or you can create a `CGPath` describing the button's shape and use `SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath:)`.  Assign the body to the button's `physicsBody` property.  Assuming you don't actually want the physics simulator to move your buttons, set each body's `dynamic` property to `false`.

Then you can use `physicsWorld.bodyAtPoint(_:)` to get one of the bodies that a touch lands on (where `physicsWorld` is a property of your `SKScene`).  Use the body's `node` property to get back to the button node. If bodies overlap, `bodyAtPoint` returns an arbitrary body.

You can use `physicsWorld.enumerateBodiesAtPoint(_:usingBlock:)` if you need all of the bodies that your touch lands on.

A completely different approach, if you can create a `CGPath` describing the button's shape, is to use `SKScene.convertPointFromView(_:)` and then `SKNode.convertPoint(_:fromNode:_)` to convert the point into the button's coordinate system, and then use `CGPathContainsPoint` (a global function) to detect whether the point is in the path describing the button shape.

Comment: @samando worth trying the last approach: `CGPathContainsPoint` method

Answer (score 0):

(I can't see your imgur link, but I think I have a pretty good idea of what you're describing.)

There are [some discussions on how to read the alpha value of out an SKTexture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438023/how-to-get-pixel-color-from-skspritenode-or-from-sktexture), but those require quite a bit of overhead for just "did I touch a parallelogram"?  Especially if you add alpha effects to your buttons.

You can do whatever logic you want on the location - you have a CGPoint that contains the location, and you know the size and shape of your buttons.

It should be pretty straightforward to write a function to test whether a point is inside a parallelogram-shaped button.  Since parallelograms are basically rectangles with triangles on each end of an "inner" rect, if you know the size of that "inner" rect, you can pretty easily determine whether the touch is where you want by:

- Checking that it's in the rect of the entire button.  If not, you know it's not in the parallelogram.
- Checking to see if it's inside the "inner" rectangle - the part of the parallelogram with the triangles "chopped off" the ends.  If so, then you know it's in the parallelogram.
- Checking to see if it's inside one of the triangles.  You know how far up and how far across the touch is in the rect that contains the triangle, and you know the slope of the line that divides that rect to make the triangle by virtue of its width and height.  That makes it trivial to check whether the point is in the triangle or not - just use the "y=mx+b" formula for a line, where m is the slope and b is whatever you need to add to get the line to pass through the corner of the rect (typically your "y intercept").  If the y coordinate is less than/greater than m*(the x coordinate) + b, you can determine whether the touch is inside or outside that triangle.

Once you have that function, you can use it as the test for checking each button.