# spritekit make childnode not touchable

Tags: sprite-kit

I have a menu button (skSpriteNode) and a small play icon inside this sprite

```
mainButton.addChild (playIcon)
mainButton.name = "xyz"
addchild (mainButton)
```

ok, I gave the button the name to check if a sprite with this name is touched.

when I touch the icon child inside the button, the touchedNode.name is nil. I set isUserInteractionEnabled = false for the icon child. I want to pass the touch to the parent. how can I do this.

```
  for touch in touches {

            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            let touchedNode  = self.atPoint(location)

            if (touchedNode.name != nil) {
                print ("node \(touchedNode.name!)")
            } else {
                continue
            }
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to implement `touchesBegan` in a subclass of `SKSpriteNode` and to set its `isUserInteractionEnabled = true`, in order to accept and process the touches for that particular node (button).

```
import SpriteKit

protocol ButtonDelegate:class {

    func printButtonsName(name:String?)
}

class Button : SKSpriteNode{

    weak var delegate:ButtonDelegate?

    init(name:String){
        super.init(texture: nil, color: .purple, size: CGSize(width: 250, height: 250))
        self.name = name
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let icon = SKSpriteNode(color: .white, size: CGSize(width:100, height:100))
        addChild(icon)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {



        delegate?.printButtonsName(name: self.name)
    }  
}

class GameScene: SKScene, ButtonDelegate {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        let button = Button(name:"xyz")
        button.delegate = self


        button.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX - 50.0, y: frame.midY)


        addChild(button)

    }

    func printButtonsName(name: String?) {

        if let buttonName = name {
            print("Pressed button : \(buttonName) ")
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this button will *swallow* the touches and the icon sprite will be ignored.

I just modified the code from [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36524132/3402095) of my answers to make an example specific to your needs, but you can read, in that link, about whole thing more in detail if interested.

Comment: thanks, I learned a few things. How can I check if the touch location is on a transparent pixel? when I have two buttons with amorph form, but overlapping rect areas, the first in the zposition is clicked.

Comment: @bluelemonade That could be solved in at least two ways (eg extracting a pixel alpha value using CGImage) or making a physics body of an irregular shape (well this really depends on a shape) and use PhysicsWorld's `bodyAt(point:)` method. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20932809/3402095

Comment: ok, I can detect the alpha of the texture. but the touch event didn't 'bubble' to the underlaying button.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the button Touchbegan and tried to implement a subclass for a slider with a background and the child thumb inside the slider. I added the sliderDelegate Protocoll in my GameScene. the down touch is ok, but I didn't get the moved in

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit


protocol SliderDelegate:class {

    func touchesBeganSKSpriteNodeSlider(name:String?, location: CGPoint?)
    func touchesMovedSKSpriteNodeSlider(name:String?, location: CGPoint?)
    func touchesEndedSKSpriteNodeSlider(name:String?, location: CGPoint?)

}


class SKSpriteNodeSlider : SKSpriteNode{

    weak var delegate:SliderDelegate?

    init(imageNamed: String){

        // super.init(imageNamed: imageNamed)
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: imageNamed)
        super.init(texture: texture, color: .white, size: texture.size())
        // self.name = name
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        // let icon = SKSpriteNode(color: .white, size: CGSize(width:100, height:100))
        // addChild(icon)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")

    }


    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        // for touch in touches {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let loc = touch.location(in: self)
            delegate?.touchesBeganSKSpriteNodeSlider(name: self.name, location: loc)

        }

    }


    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        print ("touchesMoved")

        // for touch in touches {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let loc = touch.location(in: self)
            delegate?.touchesMovedSKSpriteNodeSlider(name: self.name, location: loc)
         }

    }


    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let loc = touch.location(in: self)
            delegate?.touchesEndedSKSpriteNodeSlider(name: self.name, location: loc)
        }

    }

}
```