# How to give to sprite exact touch place?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, textures, skspritenode

**My question is**

When i touch black arrow areas i still touch whole picture, but i want only touch and have action when i **touch red area only**.
I tried to give a name to spriteNode `plane = childNode(withName: "play")` but it take/touch all image frame not only alphaBody.

[red and black areas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ocUZ.png)

I did some searches on google but no positive results.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a really simple solution could be to put hit test areas on your plane object (I've left them slightly red for the example but you would make them transparent). I created my plane class in the editor and dragged it as a reference into my scene, but you could easily just program the hit zones from scratch as well.

[image]

Then in your plane class add them to the plane and detect touches within the plane class itself. It's not exact but not that much farther off then your alpha tracing was in your picture.

A nice bonus of this method is that you can isolate this touches to areas of the plane. Some uses for that could be...

- touch left/right wing to turn that direction
- touch body to refuel
- touch wings to change guns

here is the code I used in my Plane class

```
class Plane: SKSpriteNode {

    private var background: SKSpriteNode!
    private var wingsHitTest: SKSpriteNode!
    private var bodyHitTest: SKSpriteNode!
    private var smallWingsHitTest: SKSpriteNode!

    init() {

        super.init(texture: nil, color: .clear, size: CGSize.zero)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {

        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.color = .clear

        if let background = self.childNode(withName: "//background") as? SKSpriteNode {
            self.background = background
        }

        if let wingsHitTest = self.childNode(withName: "//wingsHitTest") as? SKSpriteNode {
            self.wingsHitTest = wingsHitTest
        }

        if let bodyHitTest = self.childNode(withName: "//bodyHitTest") as? SKSpriteNode {
            self.bodyHitTest = bodyHitTest
        }

        if let smallWingsHitTest = self.childNode(withName: "//smallWingsHitTest") as? SKSpriteNode {
            self.smallWingsHitTest = smallWingsHitTest
        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        if let touch = touches.first as UITouch? {

            let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)

            if wingsHitTest.contains(touchLocation) {
                print("hit in the wings")
            }
            else if smallWingsHitTest.contains(touchLocation) {
                print("hit in the back wings")
            }
            else if bodyHitTest.contains(touchLocation) {
                print("hit in the body")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: glad it worked for you, please check it as correct so that others can benefit from this question and answer

Comment: and there is no other option to do it with full shape of texture, included parts that are now not touchable ?

Answer (score 1):

[It seems like](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7611) the behavior you want is not included in SpriteKit so you will have to implement it yourself.

Quoting from the link above:

> You will have to find out the `locationInNode(spriteNode)` of the `UITouch` object object to get the coordinates within the sprite and then read the alpha value from the sprite Image (not trivial) or precompute bitmasks (ones and zeros) from your images and read the value at the corresponding point in the bitmask for the sprite

So you will need to load your image as UIImage or CGImage and check whether the color at the pixels where the touch occurred was transparent or not. You can find more information on how to do that in this question: [How to get pixel color from SKSpriteNode or from SKTexture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438023/how-to-get-pixel-color-from-skspritenode-or-from-sktexture)

Comment: Wow also a good way of doing this, thank you you also open my minde. thank you for your answer!