# CGRectIntersectsRect with UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, cgrect, cgrectintersectsrect

I have this image in PNG format [link](http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100926194745/clubpenguin/images/archive/3/3e/20141229152855!Giant_Candy_Cane.PNG). I inserted this image in my application through a imageView.

All I'm trying to do is detect when another imageView slope that my candy cane image, for that, I used the code below:

```
CGRectIntersectsRect(self.bird.frame, TunelBot.frame)
```

But there is a small problem, my bird image was not even playing the Candy Cane image the CGRect already recognizes the touch, this is because the imageView have a rectangular shape, and the candy cane image has another shape.

Now, what I could to do, to detect when the image of the bird intersects in real shape of my candy cane image?

Comment: To begin with, you somehow need to define what area of the image is the candycane.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to test whether a given point of the drawing is transparent, as I explain here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3763313/341994