# CGContext.init() -- NULL color space no longer allowed

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

TL;DR: In legacy Obj-C code, the color space param value was `NULL`. That is not allowed in the Swift equivalent. What value to use?

I have inherited code that reads:

```
unsigned char pixel[1] = {0};
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(
    pixel,1, 1, 8, 1, NULL, (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaOnly
);
```

The port to Swift 4 `CGContext` is straightforward, except for that `NULL` color space value. Using a plausible value, I am getting `nil` back from `CGContext.init?()`. My translation is:

```
var pixelValue = UInt8(0)
var pixel = Data(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start:&pixelValue, count:1))
let context = CGContext(
    data            : &pixel,
    width           : 1,
    height          : 1,
    bitsPerComponent: 8,
    bytesPerRow     : 1,
    space           : CGColorSpace(name:CGColorSpace.genericRGBLinear)!,
    bitmapInfo      : CGImageAlphaInfo.alphaOnly.rawValue
)! // Returns nil; unwrapping crashes
```

**Q**: What is the appropriate value for `space`? (The value I provide is not returning `nil`; it's the `CGContext()` call itself.

Setting the environment variable `CGBITMAP_CONTEXT_LOG_ERRORS` yields an error log like this:

```
Assertion failed: (0), function get_color_model_name, 
file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Quartz2D_Sim/
Quartz2D-1129.2.1/CoreGraphics/API/CGBitmapContextInfo.c, line 210.
```

For some more backstory, the context was used to find the alpha value of a single pixel in a `UIImage` in the following way:

```
unsigned char pixel[1] = {0};
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixel,1, 1, 8, 1, NULL, (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaOnly);
UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
[image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(-point.x, -point.y)];
UIGraphicsPopContext();
CGContextRelease(context);
CGFloat alpha = pixel[0]/255.0;
```

(I do have possible alternatives for finding alpha, but in the interest of leaving legacy code alone, would like to keep it this way.)

Comment: Have you looked at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcolorspace/1408921-init

Comment: Try the `linearGray` color space.

Comment: @DonMag, I did read the documentation. That's how I found the `ColorSpace` names. Which I did use in the call as shown above.

Comment: @rmaddy, thank you, that did allow the initialization of CGContext. Alas, the Swift 4 version of the (rest of) the code calculates 0 for every alpha. But I do believe you answered my question.

Comment: @AndrewDuncan, did you ever find a solution for the wrong alpha calculation?

Answer (score 2):

I recently worked with similar topic, maybe this code sample will help someone:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "2.png")
guard let cgImage = image?.cgImage else {
    fatalError()
}

let width = cgImage.width
let height = cgImage.height
//CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray - 1 component, 8 bits
//i.e. 1px = 1byte
let bytesPerRow = width
let bitmapByteCount = width * height

let bitmapData: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> = .allocate(capacity: bitmapByteCount)
defer {
    bitmapData.deallocate()
}
bitmapData.initialize(repeating: 0, count: bitmapByteCount)

guard let context = CGContext(data: bitmapData, width: width, height: height,
                              bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,
                              space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray(), bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.alphaOnly.rawValue) else {
                                fatalError()
}
//draw image to context
var rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
context.draw(cgImage, in: rect)

// Enumerate through all pixels
for row in 0..<height {
    for col in 0..<width {
        let alphaValue = bitmapData[row * width + col]
        if alphaValue != 0 {
            //visible pixel
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s how to determine whether a pixel is transparent:

```
    let info = CGImageAlphaInfo.alphaOnly.rawValue
    let pixel = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity:1)
    defer {
        pixel.deinitialize(count: 1)
        pixel.deallocate()
    }
    pixel[0] = 0
    let sp = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
    let context = CGContext(data: pixel,
        width: 1, height: 1, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 1,
        space: sp, bitmapInfo: info)!
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context)
    im.draw(at:CGPoint(-point.x, -point.y))
    UIGraphicsPopContext()
    let p = pixel[0]
    let alpha = Double(p)/255.0
    let transparent = alpha < 0.01
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record, here is how I wound up doing it. It hasn't (yet) misbehaved, so on the principle of "If it ain't broke, don't fix it" I'll leave it. (I have added `self` for clarity.) But you can be sure that I will paste Matt's code right in there, in case I need it in the future. Thanks Matt!

```
// Note that "self" is a UIImageView; "point" is the point under consideration.

let im = self.image!

// TODO: Why is this clamping necessary? We get points outside our size.
var x = point.x
var y = point.y
if x < 0 { x = 0 } else if x > im.size.width  - 1 { x = im.size.width  - 1 }
if y < 0 { y = 0 } else if y > im.size.height - 1 { y = im.size.height - 1 }

let screenWidth    = self.bounds.width
let intrinsicWidth = im.size.width

x *= im.scale * intrinsicWidth/screenWidth
y *= im.scale * intrinsicWidth/screenWidth

let pixData = im.cgImage?.dataProvider?.data
let data    = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixData!)

let pixIndex = Int(((Int(im.size.width*im.scale) * Int(y)) + Int(x)) * 4)

let r = data?[pixIndex]
let g = data?[pixIndex + 1]
let b = data?[pixIndex + 2]
let α = data?[pixIndex + 3]

let red    = CGFloat(r!)/255
let green  = CGFloat(g!)/255
let blue   = CGFloat(b!)/255
let alpha  = CGFloat(α!)/255
```